# Efficient Way To Pull ith Value from Java HashMap?

Tags: java, performance, hashmap, iterator

Hello Java People,

I'm learning Java HashMaps.  While I love how easy it is to put them together, I'm mulling on a way to pull out the ith entry from the map in an efficient way.  To explain...

Let's say this is my code:

```
package HashPackage;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class newHashObject {

    // Nested class
    public class newObject {
        int Data1;
        int Data2;
        public newObject(int a, int b){
            this.Data1 = a;
            this.Data2 = b;
        }
    }

    // HashMap to contain newObjects
    HashMap<Integer, newObject> cache = new HashMap<Integer, newObject>();

    // Constructor
    public newHashObject(){
        // populate cache with 1000 newObjects:
        for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
            cache.put(i, new newObject(i, i*2+101));
        System.out.println("New cache created, total objects in cache: "+cache.size());
    }
}
```

Okay, nothing radical so far.  In real life, the entries in my HashMap would not be filed with keys equal to 0, 1, 2, 3... etc., but would be filed with essentially random number keys.  i.e., if you were to inspect my "real-life" HashMap, you'd see entries with keys 19, 79, 235, 577, 1023, 1092... etc.

Now let's say I had a need to pull out exactly the ith element from the HashMap.  I will not know the key value in advance.  For example, using the above "real-life" map:  If we started numbering the entries of the map with 0 and I wanted to pull out the i=4th entry, then I should get the entry with key 1023.

I've thought about this, and I guess I could just iterate through my HashMap from 0 to i:

```
    import java.util.Iterator;
    ...
    // Is there a better way to do this?
    public newObject iterateByIndex(int index){
        Iterator<Integer> keySetIterator = cache.keySet().iterator();
        int count=0;
        if(index<cache.size()){
            while(keySetIterator.hasNext()){
                Integer key = keySetIterator.next();
                if(count==index){
                    // We've found the ith entry in the cache
                    return cache.get(key);
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This code works, but it seems clunky and if definitely inefficient.  I'll be needing to call this method potentially millions of times (no lie!), and iterating from 0 to i each time will be a big time drain.

So... any advice?  Is a HashMap the wrong data structure here?  (I'm using a HashMap because my data set is very, very large.)  I'm curious what more seasoned programmers might do here in this situation.

Thank you for any advice,
   -P

Comment: If you need to reference something in a HashMap at the "ith" element, you are using the wrong data structure.

Comment: `HashMap` has no defined ordering, so "i-th" is not a defined concept. "This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time."

Comment: Specifically, the Map interface does not convey any sort of ordering. There are some implementations of Map that are ordered, like TreeMap and LinkedHashMap. You could look at those. (It should be noted, though, that these only grant a "predictable iteration order" - you can't just ask for the 425th entry without iterating through the first 424. Not ideal!)

Comment: @AndyTurner I agree, and even a `TreeMap`, which is a sorted map, does not necessarily expose access to an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name, "*hash* map," implies, the underlying data-structure is a "hash table."  Conceptually, it is a series of "buckets," and the key is "hashed" to determine which (one) bucket to look through to try to find that key.  This is a very efficient data structure for looking for keys by value, but it has no concept of "order."

Java has a very rich selection of data structure alternatives: trees of various kinds, collections and so-on. Even good ol' *arrays!* You need to select a different structure that is more suitable to your needs.

(And remember that something can be "in" ... that is to say, "referred-to by" ... more than one such container at a time, in much the same way that an SQL table might have more than one index.)

Comment: Extremely helpful, thanks!  I'll think about those buckets when I'm writing the next version of this code.  :)

Answer (score 3):

`HashMap` does not preserve the order of insertion.

If you always want to retrieval of your data based on index values or their order of insertion, then **I would suggest using a `List`** implementation like an `ArrayList` which gurantees the order of insertion.

You could create a wrapper object around your main data object  and put them in the `ArrayList` and when you need to read it, you could use `get` method using the index value which you want to read.

Answer (score 2):

`HashMap` is not intended to be used this way, because the order of entries is not guaranteed. You are better of using an `ArrayList`, or a `LinkedHashMap` if you really need the key->value structure.

Answer (score 2):

There is no efficient way to pull the i'th entry from a `HashMap`.  Indeed the i'th entry from a `HashMap` is not even a well-defined concept, since the ordering of the entries in a `HashMap` is unspecified.

(By contrast, the entries of a `LinkedHashMap` can be iterated in the order that the entries were inserted.  Yet even for a `LinkedHashMap` there is no way to "index" the entries apart from iterating from the start, which is an `O(I)` operation where `I` is the index of the element you are trying to retrieve.)

Bottom line: if you want efficient (i.e. `O(1)`) lookup using an index, you should use an `ArrayList` or a primitive array.

(Or, maybe, use the index values as the keys for your hash table, or for a separate hash table of the entries in a primary hash table.  But then you are talking about a more complicated data structure and / or a different model of "indexing".)

Comment: Awesome, thanks Stephen!  I was hoping for a different answer, but that's okay - its cool to know these kind of limitations.  :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the key, then a HashMap is pretty useless!
Use an ArrayList or similar instead.

If your HashMap is really, really, really large (i.e. it doesn't fit in your avail. memory) then you can consider using something in the likes of:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index-093405.html

Comment: Sorry, I genuinely meant to say "thank you!"  Just reread the previous comment and was afraid it sounded sarcastic...  If so, sarcasm is totally unintentional.